# Immersed submanifold tangent to an involutive distribution

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ be a connected smooth manifold, and suppose $D \subset TM$ is a smooth distribution which is involutive (i.e. if $X,Y$ are (locally) smooth sections of $D$ then so is their Lie bracket $[X,Y]$).  Fix some $p_0 \in M$.  Then by the Frobenius theorem there is a unique maximal connected immersed integral submanifold for $D$ passing through $p_0$; call it $N$.  Let's suppose that $N$ is not only immersed but actually embedded, so we can honestly say $N \subset M$.  Then "integral for $D$" means that for each $x \in N$ we have $T_x N = D_x$.

Now suppose $L$ is another connected smooth manifold and $\Phi : L \to M$ is an immersion.  Suppose also that:

1. $p_0 \in \Phi(L)$, and
2. for each $x \in L$ we have $d\Phi_x(T_x L) \subset D_{\Phi(x)}$.

Does it follow that $\Phi(L) \subset N$?

One might be able to argue as follows.  Consider the "set" $\mathcal{L}$ of all immersions $ \tilde{\Phi} : \tilde{L} \to M$ satisfying 1 and 2, partially ordered by inclusion of their images.  Use Zorn's lemma somehow to find a maximal  $\Phi' : L' \to M$ with $\Phi(L) \subset \Phi'(L')$.  Show, using the maximality, that we in fact have $d\Phi'_x(T_x L') = D_{\Phi'(x)}$ for each $x \in L'$.  Then use the uniqueness in the Frobenius theorem to conclude $\Phi'(L') = N$.

But I am not sure how to fill in the details, and Zorn's lemma seems like too much firepower for something that seems so intuitive.

I am actually most interested in the case where $L$ is one-dimensional, so $\Phi$ is simply a smooth curve tangent to $D$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we have that. You can see it as follows: the submanifold $N$ is constructed by considering the flows of sections of the distribution (indeed, the fact that the distribution is involutive implies that the flows commute, making this construction well-defined). Now take any point $x\in L$ and consider a path $\gamma:[0,1]\to L$ going from $x_0$ to $x$. Its velocity field is tangent to the distribution, so we can extend it to a section of $D$, of which $\gamma$ will be the flow. It follows by its construction that $x\in N$.

Comment: That sounds like a good plan (I guess I should read the proof of the Frobenius theorem more carefully).  But I'm worried that $\gamma$ might have self-intersections, in which case its velocity field is not well defined.

Comment: That is, suppose we unluckily choose a $\gamma$ that looks like $\looparrowright$.  If $p$ is the point at the intersection, and $X$ is to be our smooth section of $D$, then what should $X(p)$ be?  And if we remove the loop, to make the curve injective, then it is no longer smooth.

Comment: @NateEldredge You can always bypass the problem by splitting the curve in more pieces.